# Plot multiple region with overlapping in RegionPlot3D like in RegionPlot

Tags: plotting

In RegionPlot you can do

> `RegionPlot[{x^2 < y^3 + 1, y^2 < x^3 + 1}, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}, 
>    PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`
>
> [image]

But this seem to not work for RegionPlot3D

> `RegionPlot3D[{x - 0.5*y + z <= 0, x + y + z <= 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,
>      2}, {z, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]`
>
> [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A general way to do this, that allows you to play with colors and transparencies:

```
Show[
 RegionPlot3D[x - 0.5*y + z <= 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}], 
 RegionPlot3D[x + y + z <= 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the intersection:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x - 0.5*y + z <= 0 && x + y + z <= 0, 
{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and union :

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x - 0.5*y + z <= 0 || x + y + z <= 0, 
{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]